# is it possible to make setup for WebService?

Tags: c#, web-services

is it possible to make setup installation for WebService ?

that the installation will make the Virtual directory + the IIS setup + all the Permissions

if it possible, how to do it ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With IIS 7 and Visual Studio 2010 you can create installation packages that includes instructions for IIS7 so that the installation takes care of the settings.

Check this out: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx